# Changing sub-menu text size and color in Sherlock action bar android

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, submenu, textcolor

I am developing small android application in which I am using Sherlock action bar. In my action bar i am using sub-menu. Every thing is working fine only problem is that i am not able to override style of that sub-menu text.I want to change color and text of sub menu title and drop down list text color and size.  I tried this in following way ...

```
// displaying sub menu
 SubMenu subMenu1 = menu.addSubMenu("Coupons");
    subMenu1.add("Co1");
    subMenu1.add("co2");
    subMenu1.add("co3");

    MenuItem subMenu1Item = subMenu1.getItem();
    //subMenu1Item.setIcon(R.drawable.fb_br);
    subMenu1Item.setTitle("Cards");
    subMenu1Item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
```

and I tried to override style of text in style.xml like in this way

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
<item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/MyDropDownListView</item></style>
 <style name="MyDropDownListView" parent="android:style/Widget.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

But its not working for. Am I doing some thing wrong?.. How do this.. Need help .. thank you ..

Comment: hello nilkash, did you found any way to change color of sub menu items.

Answer (score 0):

Custom define a theme like

```
   <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

This could change the menu item's color.

Or adding them in custom view xml for action bar.